# Regex for number without leading or ending zeros

Tags: regex

I am really struggling to find a regex that validates the following patterns.

Examples of patterns that should be valid:

An integer number:

```
25
100
0
```

A decimal number:

```
15.31
0.123
25.01
```

A number or decimal number followed by slash and another number or decimal number:

```
25/25
0/0
25.2/25.2
0.123/0.123
25.5/25 (decimal and integer combined)
```

A number or decimal number followed by slash and percentage symbol and another number or decimal number and percentage symbol:

```
25%/25%
0.125%/0.125%
```

The following patterns should be invalid:

```
0000 (more than one zero)
0.0
25%/25 (only one percentage symbol)
25//25 (two bar symbols)
25.00 (ending with zeros in the decimal part)
25.0500 (again ending with zeros in the decimal part)
02 (starting with a zero)
```

The following patterns are valid, but my regex is not accepting:

```
0.2%/0.1%
0.123/0.123
```

Could someone help me with this, and if possible with an explanation of the regex?

Current regex:

```
/^([1-9]\d*%?\/?|[1-9]\d*\.{1}[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]%?|^0\.[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9])(\/([1-9]\d*%?\/?|[1-9]\d*\.{1}[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]%?|^0\.[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]))*$|^0{1}$/gm
```

Regex link:
https://regex101.com/r/NtQpEB/1

Comment: what regex are you using currently

Comment: Yes.
^([1-9]\d*%?\/?|[1-9]\d*\.{1}[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]%?|^0\.[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9])(\/([1-9]\d*%?\/?|[1-9]\d*\.{1}[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]%?|^0\.[0-9]*[1-9]?[0-9]*[1-9]))*$|^0{1}$

https://regex101.com/r/NtQpEB/1

Comment: Try this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+number+no+leading+zero

Comment: A quick look on your regex: read up on quantifiers `{1,5}` etc.

Comment: An what about negative numbers?

Comment: Negative numbers can be accepted, but due to the nature of the problem, its not necessary to consider

Comment: `0.123` should that be valid?  (after reading the question 3 times, I still do not know the answer.... )    Please add a textual info about what should match, and what not, and not only examples without specifying what is should do, because "A decimal number" and then? should it be OK or not OK ?

Comment: Sorry. 0.123 yes its valid. I will edit the post to try to clarify it as much as possible

Comment: Question was unfairly closed. It has all the details and OP has been responding to queries in comments and has subsequently edited question to clarify the requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this regex to match all of your cases:

```bash
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:0*[1-9])+)?(%?)(?:/(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:0*[1-9])+)?\1)?$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NtQpEB/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:[1-9]\d*|0)`: Match a `0` or digits starting with `1-9`
- `(?:\.(?:0*[1-9])+)?`: Optional part after `.` that uses `(?:0*[1-9])+` to makes sure that it doesn't end with a zero
- `(%?)`: Match optional `%` and capture in group #1
- `(?:/(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:0*[1-9])+)?\1)?`: Optional part that comes after matching `/`. Note that we use `\1` as back-reference here to make sure if `%` has been matched before `/` then it should be matched in 2nd part as well
- `$`: End

Comment: Reading this really cool regex, OP should clarify whether `25/0` is valid.

Comment: @Aeronautix: Thanks. As per my understanding from OP if `0` is valid then `25/0` will also be valid.